# Cannot find files on internal HDD

Tags: file-search

My Fedora system is installed on my SSD, and GNOME can easily find files there.

However, files on an automounted internal HDD are not found.

Is there a way to make GNOME index the HDD?

I'm referring to the GNOME Shell search, which I believe uses some improved version of `locate`:

[image]

You can see how GNOME found `/home/jan/Code`, which is on my SSD. But if I input "TV", it won't find anything, since it's on the HDD.

Comment: How do you search them?

Comment: @Braiam Good call, I was making the question in a hurry. I'm referring to GNOME Shells search, see the edited question

Comment: @don_crissti OK so I've changed the gid and uid of the drive, symlinked it to `home/Data`, and I can find that through search, but still cannot find anything *inside*. For example when I search for "TV" still nothing relevant shows up. I've deleted tracker data and cache and restarted.

Comment: @don_crissti Nice, it works now! I had to enable the bookmark "Data" in the search preferences.